# Manga where the protagonist is banished from the Hero's party, and then later defeats the demon general by crushing his heart

Tags: story-identification, manga

I forgot the name of a manga where the protagonist rescues his party, but only rescues like one girl and a cat girl. He defeats the demon general by crushing the demon general's heart.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When and where did you read this?  Please check out the other [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11874/101407) to see if the help you recall any more details you can [edit] into your question.

Comment: *"I Was Kicked out of the Hero's Party Because I Wasn't a True Companion so I Decided to Have a Slow Life at the Frontier"*?

Comment: @Lemege - If anyone correctly identifies the manga you're looking for, please mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons. Or if the only answers posted are incorrect, please indicate that with a comment so we know to keep looking. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is ***[The Strongest Sorcerer Who Makes Full Use of the "Strategy Guide"](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=155370)***.

From Baka-Updates:

> Magnus is a skilled wizard with the ability to use various attributes.
> Unfortunately the leader of his party orders him to cast spells that have no effect on the monsters they fight. The members of his party think he's useless and mistreat him, one night, after another bout of insults, he is expelled from his party. Downtrodden he's approached by a merchant who saw how he was mistreated and is gifted a certain book… A book containing the entirety of the world's knowledge.
>
> Now it's his turn to shine and rise above the party that thought him to be useless.

After the main character -- a sorcerer named Magnus -- is kicked out from the Hero's party, he learns that they've replaced him with a cat girl.

Later in the story, the Hero's party confronts the "Evil Cursed General" Derbenvot, in his fortress, and he makes short work of them, noting how unbalanced they are without a sorcerer on their team.

Magnus then shows up, and while he and Derbenvot are fighting, Derbenvot gloats that he can't be killed as long as his heart pulsates, and he already pulled his heart from his chest and hid it to keep it safe. However, Magnus reveals that he has Derbenvot's heart -- which resembles a glass sphere -- and hurls it to the floor, shattering it and killing Derbenvot.

Magnus is then hugged and thanked by the two remaining members of the Hero's party, a female fighter named Misha, and the cat girl.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Also the answer at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/243544/isekai-manga-where-op-is-a-weak-magician-in-a-hero-party-and-gets-stronger-with/243547#243547, albeit unaccepted.